# After compiling Typescript to javascript, in code before imported function adds module name with suffix "_1"

Tags: javascript, d3.js, typescript, amd, queue.js

I am trying to rewrite some js/d3.js code in ts/amd. But i have a problem with importing of libraries. That is structure of my .ts file:

```
/// <reference path="d3.d.ts"/>;
/// <reference path="queue.d.ts"/>;
import * as d3 from "d3"; 
import {queue} from "./queue";

export class Glob{

    ...

    queue().defer(d3.json, "world-110m.json")
           .defer(d3.tsv, "world-110m-country-names.tsv")
           .await(this.draw);    

    ...

}
```

But when that code compiles, i have additional mudule **queue_1** before function statement:

```
define(["require", "exports", "d3", "./queue"], function (require, exports, d3, queue_1) {
"use strict";

    ...

    Glob.prototype.init = function (class_name) {
        ...
        queue_1.queue()
               .defer(d3.json, "world-110m.json")
               .defer(d3.tsv, "world-110m-country-names.tsv")
               .await(this.draw);
         ...
    }

    ...

}
```

And if I am using it, it gives me error: **queue_1.queue is not a function**. But if I deleting **queue** directly in generated .js file, and leave just **queue_1()**, it is works fine!

So, I need to import just a function. How to do that?

Comment: Try setting a different module system in your tsconfig.json file and see how that goes. For instance set it to "commonjs"

Comment: Thank you for advice, but i have already solve this problem. I simply found special version of library espatialy for DefinitelyTyped. But i think that this system is still not good ...